# Solve the Differential Equation using differential formulae

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In these questions, we are allowed to use the following differential formulae (or anything similar or combination of these):
$$
\begin{split}
d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) &= \frac{ydx-xdy}{y^2} \\
\\
d(xy) &= ydx+xdy\\
\\
d\left(\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right) &= \frac{ydx-xdy}{xy}\\
\\
(x^2+y^2) &= 2(xdx+ydy) \\
\\
d\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)&=\frac{ydx-xdy}{x^2+y^2}
\end{split}$$

The three problems I am stuck at are:

1. $$(y-xy^2)dx+(x+x^2y^2)dy =0 $$
   **Attempt**
   $$ydx+xdy = xy^2dx-x^2y^2dy$$
   I noticed the LHS could be multiple things such as $d\left(\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)\cdot xy$, $d(xy)$ etc...
   Then, I tried this:
   $$
   \begin{split}
   xyd(\ln(xy) &=xy^2(dx-xdy)\\
   \implies d(\ln(xy))&=y(dx-xdy)
   \end{split}$$
   Now this is where I am stuck, I have to express the RHS either in some differential formula (which I am unable to do) or to re-express the LHS so that after simplifying, the RHS will only be of "1 variable".
2. $$x dy -ydx = x^2y^4(xdy+ydx)$$
3. $$xdy+ydx+x^2y^5dy=0$$
   I tried using combination of the above formulae in all of them, such as $d\left(\ln\right(\frac{x^2}{y^2}\left)\right) $ etc., but couldn't solve it this way.

I got the solutions using integrating factors and exact equations, as follows:

Solution of 1. $$-\frac{1}{xy}-\ln(x)+y=c$$

Solution of 2. $$3x+x^3y^4+cy=0$$

Solution of 3. $$x(y^5+cy)=4$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you got the solutions why are you stuck?

Comment: Not the steps to reach the solutions, only the final answer.

Comment: Stuck using the technique required by the exercise, but not solving them using other methods.

Comment: For example, the first question in the exercise is:
$$xdy-ydx = (1+y^2)dy $$
$$-d(\frac{x}{y})*y^2=(1+y^2)dy $$
$$-d(\frac{x}{y})=(y^{-2}+1)dy $$
$$-\frac{x}{y}=-\frac{1}{y}+y+c$$ 
This is the way they want these to be solved I guess.

Comment: You do not have tell us trivial differential formulas you are allowed to use. If your task is to find the integrating factors you may want to study this [script](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/2233-S99/2233-l12.pdf). If there are further question we need to know exactly where you are stuck. Regarding your last comment: you guess that this is the way "they" want these to be solved. What answer to you expect from me on this?

Comment: I don't get it. It is not the goal of this exercise to find Integrating factors nor to solve them using exact equations. I illustrated the approach above. The author asks us to manipulate the given equation to some "familiar" differential formula which allows one to integrate it directly as shown above. I.e. d(something) = (Something easy to integrate in 1 variable) 

Well I have to tell the "trivial" differnetial formulas, as the author did, so that one knows the answer is just manipulation of these, and not other ones.
I will edit (i) to show where I am exactly stuck if this helps.

Comment: Regarding "guess"; It just means I understood that is what they want. Maybe I am correct maybe not. I posted the title of the exercise and listed the formulae so that you can decide what the question "exactly is", if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved them.

I will post the answers so that if it is asked in the future, then the steps are provided here.

For (i): $$y dx + xdy = xy^2dx-x^2y^2dy$$
$$\implies d(xy) = x^2y^2(\frac{dx}{x}-dy)$$
$$\implies \frac{d(xy)}{x^2y^2}=d(\ln(x)-y) $$
$$\implies \int \frac{d(xy)}{(xy)^2} = \int d(\ln(x)-y) $$
$$\implies -\frac{1}{xy} = \ln(x)-y + c \iff -\frac{1}{xy}-\ln(x)+y=c$$

For (ii): $$xdy-ydx =x^2y^4(xdy+ydx)$$
$$\implies x^2d(\frac{y}{x})=x^2y^4d(xy) $$
$$\implies d(\frac{y}{x})=y^4d(xy)$$

Here we multiply both sides by $\frac{x^2}{y^2}:$
$$\implies (\frac{y}{x})^{-2}d(\frac{y}{x})=(xy)^2d(xy) $$
$$\implies \int (\frac{y}{x})^{-2}d(\frac{y}{x})= \int (xy)^2d(xy) $$
$$\implies -\frac{x}{y}=\frac{(xy)^3}{3}+c $$
$$\implies -3x=x^3y^4+cy \iff 3x+x^3y^4+cy=0 $$

For (iii): $$xdy+ydx+x^2y^5=9$$
$$\implies d(xy)=-(xy)^2y^3dy $$
$$\implies -\frac{d(xy)}{(xy)^2} = y^3dy$$
$$\implies \int -\frac{d(xy)}{(xy)^2}=\int y^3 dy $$
$$\implies \frac{1}{xy}=\frac{y^4}{4}+c \iff x(y^5+cy)=4 $$